# Form close without updating database table - ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a popup form which lets user to submit information. I want the modal to close after user hits submit. It does actually close but doesn't submit anything to the database. Here's the code

```
.form-actions#submitButton
            = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success btn-primary col-sm-offset-5"

 :javascript
   $('#submitButton').click(function() {
     $('#landslide-submit-modal').modal('hide');
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys. The problem was indentation. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Assure that you are specifying what model the form is for, then rails will know where to submit the entry.

Comment: If I delete the javascript bit, the form will be successfully submitted but it doesn't close

Answer (score 0):

Change function and try with:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
  $('#landslide-submit-modal').modal('hide');
  return false;
});
```